# Passing on lifetimes of underlying reference fields?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make two structs that operate on an underlying dataset; one providing immutable "read" operations, the other allowing modification. For this to work, I need to be able to use the read functions from within the modifying object - as such I create a temporary new read object within the modifier function with a view onto the underlying data.

Here's some code:

```
struct Read<'db> {
    x: &'db i32
}

impl<'db> Read<'db> {
    pub fn get(&'db self) -> &'db i32 { self.x }
}

struct Write<'db> {
    x: &'db mut i32
}

impl<'db> Write<'db> {
    fn new(x: &mut i32) -> Write { Write{x: x} }

    fn as_read(&'db self) -> Read<'db> {
        Read{x: self.x}
    }

    pub fn get(&'db self) -> &'db i32 { self.as_read().get() }
}    


fn main() {
    let mut x = 69i32;
    let y = Write::new(&mut x);
    println!("{}", y.get());
}
```

It doesn't compile - it seems that despite my best efforts, the lifetime of the reference returned from `Read::get` is bound to the `Write::get`'s scope, rather than the `Write`'s `'db` lifetime. How can I make it compile? (And, is what I want to do possible? Is it the simplest/most concise way of doing it?)

Answer (score 4):

The point the compiler is trying to get across is that `&'db self` actually means `self: &'db Write<'db>`. This means that you tie the reference AND the type to the same lifetime. What you actually want in your case is `self: &'a Write<'db>` where `'a` lives just for the `as_read` function. To be able to return a `'db` reference from a `'a` reference, you need to specify that `'a` lives at least as long as `'db` by constraining `'a: 'db`.

```
fn as_read<'a: 'db>(self: &'a Write<'db>) -> Read<'db> {
    Read{x: self.x}
}

pub fn get<'a: 'db>(self: &'a Write<'db>) -> &'db i32 { self.as_read().get() }
```

or more concisely

```
fn as_read<'a: 'db>(&'a self) -> Read<'db> {
    Read{x: self.x}
}

pub fn get<'a: 'db>(&'a self) -> &'db i32 { self.as_read().get() }
```

[Try it out in the Playground](http://is.gd/urbO47)

Comment: What is strange is that if the struct doesn't store a `&mut`, then you [don't need the `'a` at all](http://is.gd/pbhLxP). That seems a little odd.

Comment: Not at all. If you could call `as_read()` multiple times, you'd end up with two `&mut` to the i32. You can see that you can use @Wavin's code if you reborrow as immutable in `as_read`: http://is.gd/Nt66hL this would probably be the better answer. I'll update my code

Comment: *you'd end up with two &mut to the i32* — I must be missing how. Since `Read` only stores an immutable reference, I'd expect the mutable -> immutable reborrow to happen automatically. Also I **totally** did `&*self.x` and it didn't work. Now I'm going crazy.

Comment: uhm. right, no Idea what's going on. There's probably already an issue about this... but I can't find it right now

Comment: Ah, your version works because you have `&'db self`. While I understand how that would work, I feel like just `&self` should work as well. Lifetime elision would insert a `'a` for `self`, but it doesn't matter because we are copying the inner reference and its lifetime. Maybe the copy doesn't work *because* of the `mut`?

Comment: `&mut` is always reborrowed or moved, but can't be copied. I guess rustc can't figure out `'a:'db` even though that should be obvious here.

Comment: the issue now is that `'a` is declared to outlive `'db`, which it definitely doesn't. `'a` is a temporary object created in a function call to another object (`Write`) which itself outlives `db`.